# the for loop exit after it has been executed one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

the **for** loop in the following code exit after removing one class and doesn't remove the other one unless I click the button again

I want to remove the class **hidden** from 2 divs but I don't want to use **querySelectorAll**.

is there any way to do it using **getElementsByClassName** and **for** loop, without JQuery **Just JavaScript**

I did the same thing before but it was to change the style of something not to add or remove classes.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');

let show = document.querySelector('.show-modal');

show.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        items.item(i).classList.remove('hidden');  
    }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use getElementsByClassName for show-modal too

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a _live_ HTMLCollection, meaning all changes to the DOM will be reflected in `items` immediately. When you remove the class from an item, it disappears from that collection immediately, changing the length of the collection as well. This can simply be worked around, if you iterate over the collection backwards instead of forwards. Or use `querySelectorAll` instead to begin with - that one returns a _static_ NodeList.

Comment: @TusharShahi i can use it but it's only one item and I just use query to demonstrate

Comment: @CBroe how to iterate backward i didn't get it?

Comment: `for (let i = items.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Comment: @CBroe but I didn’t understand why it works backward but not forward ? If you have time could you please explain it?

Comment: I already explained that, with my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a forEach would help -

```js
show.addEventListener('click', () => {
    items.forEach((element) => {
        element.classList.remove('hidden');  
    })
});
```

Comment: will thank you for your help but I want to use for loop to prove my point 

Comment: @AliAb then use querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName as the latter returns a live list

Comment: So there is no way to use getElementsByClassName with for loop to do it?

Comment: @AliAB if you iterate backwards it would work - but why your fixation on using it?

Comment: it worked backwards, it was a challenge between me and my teacher cuz I’m new in javascript